# How to join three tables and put it in a ViewModel using LINQ Lambda in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm having a problem trying to join three table data and put it into a viewmodel.

Here is my code:

```
var idSearchJoin = payoutdb.payout_transaction    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
               .Join(payoutdb.payout_remittance, // the source table of the inner join
               transaction => transaction.transid, // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
               remit => remit.transid,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
               (transaction, remit) => new TransactionReport() // selection
                {
                   transid = transaction.transid,
                   senderRefId = transaction.senderRefId,
                   senderName = transaction.senderName,
                   senderAddr = transaction.senderAddr,
                   batchid = transaction.batchid,
                   requestDate = transaction.requestDate,
                   benefName = transaction.benefName,
                   benefacctno = transaction.benefacctno,
                   amount = remit.amount,
                   purpose = remit.purpose,
                   status = transaction.status
               })
               .Join(payoutdb.payout_bank,
               remit => remit.receivingbank,
               bank => bank.bankid,
               (remit,bank) => new TransactionReport()
               {
                   receivingbank = bank.name
               })
               .Where(transactremit => transactremit.senderRefId == searchTxt).ToList();
```

But this code produces and error `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code` The additional information `The specified type member 'receivingbank' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported`
gives me a hint to the problem but i still couldn't solve it. This code will only run if I will remove this portion of code:

```
.Join(payoutdb.payout_bank,
               remit => remit.receivingbank,
               bank => bank.bankid,
               (remit,bank) => new TransactionReport()
               {
                   receivingbank = bank.name
               })
```

But i need this portion of code in order for me to get the equivalent of the `receivingbank` from payout_transaction to the `bankid` on the payout_bank table. This is my sql code for this that work:

```
SELECT a.transid,c.name
FROM payout_transaction a
INNER JOIN 
payout_remittance b
ON a.transid = b.transid
INNER JOIN
payout_bank c
ON b.receivingbank = c.bankid
WHERE senderRefId =  searchtxt;
```

But I dont know how to do this on LINQ Lambda.Do you have any suggestions or any work around on how can i solve this?

Comment: why don't you use include()

Comment: Can you show me how should I do that?

Comment: refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I've just couldn't do it on my scenario because I'm only new to LINQ. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have relations correctly defined in the models, the joined result set can be selected in EF method syntax like this without using any Join statements :

```
var idSearchJoin = DBContext.payout_transactionDBSet                        
                  .Include(i => i.payout_remittanceNavigationProp)                                     
                  .Include(p => p.payout_bankNavigationProp)                                 
                  .Where(transactremit => transactremit.senderRefId == searchTxt)              
                  .Select(s => new TransactionReport() 
                   {
                     transid = s.transid,
                     senderRefId = s.senderRefId,
                     senderName = s.senderName,
                     senderAddr = s.senderAddr,
                     batchid = s.batchid,
                     requestDate = s.requestDate,
                     benefName = s.benefName,
                     benefacctno = s.benefacctno,
                     amount = s.payout_remittanceNavigationProp.amount,
                     purpose = s.payout_remittanceNavigationProp.purpose,
                     status = s.status,
                     receivingbank = s.payout_bankNavigationProp.name
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you so much :)